# Botão curtir dinâmico

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

seguinte, na página de cada post possui um botão para "favoritar", como posso verificar se o post já foi curtido e alterar o nome do botão para, por exemplo, "favoritado" e se não estiver, ao clicar no botão seria feito isso, mas tudo em segundo plano, tenho conhecimentos muito rasos em javascript, mas sei que precisarei de ajax para isso. já montei um pequeno script em php/mysql que retorna um json `{"favorite":1}` quando o post já está favoritado ou quando é alterado para favoritado, sendo seu estado natural `{"favorite":0}`

Como só é possível favoritar estando logado no site, o id do usuário será capturado por **session**, e o id do post será enviado através do método **POST**

Ex:

```
<a href="site.com/post/favoritar">Favoritar</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, eu acho que pra você fazer ajax seria bom usar o jQuery, fiz um pequeno código, para lhe mostrar como fazer o mesmo.

```
    <a href="site.com/post/favoritar" id="favorito">Favoritar</a>

    <!-- Dependencias -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var btnFavorito = document.querySelector('#favorito');

        $(function(){

            alteraStatus();

            // altera texto do botão
            function alteraStatus(){
                var json = {"favorite":1,"userLogged" : true};
                if(json.userLogged){
                    if(json.favorite === 1)
                        btnFavorito.innerHTML = 'Favoritado';
                    else
                        btnFavorito.innerHTML = 'Favoritar';
                }
            }

            // Favoritar
            function favoritar(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "server.json"
                }).done(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    alteraStatus(data);
                });
            }
            $(btnFavorito).on('click',favoritar);
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você salva essa ação de favoritar no banco de dados? Se sim, é só você usar o Ajax na página verificando se o usuário favoritou o item relacionado o id do usuário com o id do post.